# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'confirmed' with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working to modify a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask) Flask app. This uses the flask_login usermixin.

I have a method register which contains:

```
from myflaskapp.models.user import User

if form.validate_on_submit()
    new_user = User.query.filter_by(email=posted_email).first
    if new_user:
        if new_user.confirmed:
```

The posted_email is NOT in the table so I thought that a value of None would be returned. Why is this not working?

myflaskapp.models.user:

```
from flask.ext.login import UserMixin
from myflaskapp.extensions import db, bcrypt
from myflaskapp.database import (
    Column,
    Model,
    ReferenceCol,
    relationship,
    SurrogatePK,
)



class User(UserMixin, SurrogatePK, Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'
    username = Column(db.String(80), nullable=True)
    email = Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    #: The hashed password
    password = Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)
    created_at = Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
    first_name = Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    last_name = Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    active = Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    admin = Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    confirmed_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)

>>> User.query.filter_by(email=posted_email).first
<bound method BaseQuery.first of <flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x03DF4FF0>>
>>> User.query.filter_by(email=posted_email)
<flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x03DF4030>
>>> new_user = User.query.filter_by(email=posted_email).first
>>> type(new_user)
<type 'instancemethod'>
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
  response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask_debugtoolbar\__init__.py", line 124, in dispatch_request
  return view_func(**req.view_args)
File "C:\envs\r2\mini\myflaskapp\views\public.py", line 73, in register
  if new_user.confirmed:
```

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'confirmed'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call [`first()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first), it is a method:

```
new_user = User.query.filter_by(email=posted_email).first()
```

Comment: Thanks, that was dumb..